# How do I loop php array and insert to database

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I am trying to insert these into mysql database. The first one (AAA, a) gets inserted and error shows saying cannot duplicate (AAA, a). After (AAA, a) gets inserted (BBB, b) needs to get inserted and so on.

Then another file such as this is going to run and insert into another table. Without the foreach loop this doesn't work.

```
      <?php
      use App\Role;
    use App\Permission;
 use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
 class DepartmentSeeder extends Seeder
{
/**
 * Run the database seeds.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function run()
{

    /** @var Roles */
    $default_role_list = [
        ['display_name' => 'AAA, 'name' => 'a'],
        ['display_name' => 'BBB', 'name' => 'b'],
        ['display_name' => 'CCC', 'name' => 'c'],
        ['display_name' => 'DDD', 'name' => 'd'],

    ];

    foreach ($default_role_list as $role) {
        Role::create([
            'name'         => $role['name'],
            'display_name' => $role['display_name'],
        ]);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: You got a typo in your first item in the array, you're missing a `'` at the end of AAA, not sure if it's just a typo here or general. Also could you please be more specific about what the error you are getting and what's going on, I'm having a hard time understanding what's suppose to happen and what is happening in your question.

Comment: Sorry. Yes thats just a typo. Basically im trying to insert into a table where column "display name" is supposed to be updated with "AAA" and "name" is supposed to be "a". Now with the current code that works. And then i want the next row to be updated with column "display name"  with "BBB" and "name" with "b"

Comment: However, its not going adding "BBB" and "b" and keeps on running the first line which is to add "AAA" and "a" hence the error, "AAA" has already been inserted.

Answer (score 0):

**use the below code for multidimensional array**

```
<?php
use App\Role;
use App\Permission;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
class DepartmentSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {

        /** @var Roles */
        $default_role_list = array(
                                 0 => array("display_name"=>"AAA","name"=>"a"),
                                 1 => array("display_name"=>"BBB","name"=>"b"),
                                 2 => array("display_name"=>"CCC","name"=>"c"),
                                 3 => array("display_name"=>"DDD","name"=>"d")
                            );
        $default_role_list_count =0;
        foreach ($default_role_list as $role) {
            Role::create( array(
                'name'         => $role[$default_role_list_count]['name'],
                'display_name' => $role[$default_role_list_count]['display_name'],
            ));
            $default_role_list_count++;
        }

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I am getting error
  [ErrorException]
  Undefined offset: 0